# List li first element css float not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm facing a strange problem, I'm trying to apply html template to wordpress website and it have a form and the from fields have inside HTML ul li.

But when i apply css to li the only first element not float left. I tried to fix but didn't found any solution. can some one give me a idea for fix this. i add some codes below

```
 <div class="bd">
<ul class="clearfix">
<li>
              <label>電話</label><br>
              <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-phone"><input type="text" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required text" size="40" value="" name="your-phone"></span>
            </li>
<li>
              <label>公司名字</label><br>
              <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-company"><input type="text" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required text" size="40" value="" name="your-company"></span>
            </li>
<li>
              <label>姓名</label><br>
             <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-fullname"><input type="text" aria-invalid="false" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text text" size="40" value="" name="your-fullname"></span>
            </li>
<li>
              <label>預算資金</label><br>
               <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-buject"><input type="text" aria-invalid="false" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text text" size="40" value="" name="your-buject"></span>
            </li>
<li>
              <label>電郵</label><br>
               <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" aria-invalid="false" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-email text" size="40" value="" name="your-email"></span>
            </li>
<li>
              <label>目標</label><br>
              <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-aims"><input type="text" aria-invalid="false" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text text" size="40" value="" name="your-aims"></span>
            </li>
</ul>
<div class="btn"><input type="submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" value="Send"><img class="ajax-loader" src="http://5unit.com/test/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending ..." style="visibility: hidden;">
          </div>
<p></p></div>
```

The CSS

```
.contact-box .box .bd {
  padding: 28px 0;
}

.clearfix::after {
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.contact-box .box .bd ul li {
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 43px;
  width: 580px;
}

.contact-box .box .bd ul li label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
}
```

You can see only first li centered and others and floated left well

Can someone please help me to fix this strange error

the form should be like http://awesomescreenshot.com/0b563venfe

Found a solution it happened because WordPress original css had some css effect for this but it's not directly effect somehow when i remove this css it worked

```
.entry-content h1,
.entry-summary h1,
.comment-content h1,
.textwidget h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    line-height: 1.25;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the first li to also float left?  This is what your question seems to ask.

Comment: yes it should be like this http://awesomescreenshot.com/0b563venfe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at your test site and I see the problem.

The reason is that the element before it (.box .hd. h3) has a large margin-bottom, and the floated element is pushing against that.

Ideally, override that margin-bottom and it will allow the float to work properly.

Alternatively, you can add a "clear:both;" to the first li in your ul.

Comment: A lot of times, this type of quirky behavior, especially with floating elements, is due to a neighboring or parent element's properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pseudo class
:first-of-type

Comment: not worked, i also tried to use inline style for first element but it's not float to left